# C Caesar Cipher error random string output

Tags: c, encryption

So I have been taking classes on C and one of the exercises was to program a caesar cipher program that both encrypts and decrypts. And when the input is "ab cd", the output should be "de#fg" but instead it outputs "de?g?". So my guess is the spacebar messes everything up. But also another error was found when I inputted "a" and it outputted "d?ad?". Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void cipher(char plain_str[], char cipher_str[]);
void decipher(char cipher_str[], char decipher_str[]);

int main() {
    char plain_str[30];
    char cipher_str[30];
    char decipher_str[30];

    printf("Enter plain string: ");
    scanf("%s", plain_str);

    cipher(plain_str, cipher_str);
    decipher(cipher_str, decipher_str);
}

void cipher(char plain_str[], char cipher_str[]) {
    int i = 0;

    while(plain_str[i] != '\0') {
        if((plain_str[i]+3) >= 0 && (plain_str[i]+3) <= 127) {
            cipher_str[i] = plain_str[i] + 3;
        } else {
            cipher_str[i] = plain_str[i] - 124;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", cipher_str);
}

void decipher(char cipher_str[], char decipher_str[]) {
    //asdf
}
```

Comment: You're never adding the trailing null byte to `cipher_str`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, my knowledge of C programming ends at while loops...

Comment: You've been taking a C class, and they never taught you that C strings have to end with a `\0`? Isn't that why the `while` loop tests for that?

Comment: The reason you're stopping at space is because `scanf("%s", plain_str)` only reads a single word. If you want to read a whole line, use `fgets()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%s` operator in `scanf` only reads a single word, not a whole line. So if you enter `ab cd`, only `ab` is put into `plain_str`. To read a whole line, use `fgets()`:

```
fgets(plain_str, sizeof(plain_str), stdin);
size_t len = strlen(plain_str);
if (plain_str[len-1] == '\n') {
    plain_str[len-1] = '\0'; // Remove newline
}
```

The other problem is that you're never adding the null terminator to `cipher_str`, so you're printing whatever garbage is in it after the encoded characters. The simplest way to resolve this is to initialize it to an all-zero array when you declare the variable:

```
char cipher_str[30] = {0};
```